# Script or macro that deletes certain characters in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write (or find) a script that when run, deletes everything in a column except what is between two quotation marks. It should look something like this:

Before:  `DEFAULT "443562765560"`

After:  `443562765560`

So basically it deleted everything after and before the quotation marks, just leaving what was inside.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't you just format the cells to only accept numbers (assuming that numbers are the only things you'll need afterward?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Split function:

```
MyArray = Split(TextToSplit, Delim)
```

This returns a zero based array: MyArray(0) is everything to the left of the first Delim, MyArray(1) is everything between the first and second Delim's, etc. It's a little tricky when Delim is double quotes --- I like to use Delim=Chr(34).

To extract everything between the first two double quotes you could do something like:

```
c.Formula = Split(c.Value, Chr(34))(1)
```

where c is a cell. The (1) on the end extracts element 1 from the 0-based array returned by Split.

Hope that helps.